# Echo html tag in javascript through php

Tags: php, javascript, html, firebug

I have a mysterious problem.
I have a php language array like this:

```
$lang['tip1054'] = '<b>Resource Error:</b>%s <br />
<b>OS:</b> %s <br />
<b> Ram:</b> %s <br />
<b> CPU:</b> %s <br />
';
```

I would show it in a tooltip that is written by javascript the function is used like this:

```
<span class='haveHelp' onMouseOver="ShowTip(' <?php printf ($lang['tip1054'],$error,$os,$ram,$cpu); ?> ')"> </span>
```

But it shows nothing. I used firebug to see what problem is. Faced this error:

```
SyntaxError: unterminated string literal
[Break On This Error] 

ShowTip('<b>Resource Error:</b> 1054
```

and this is HTML Output:

```
<span class='haveHelp' onMouseOver="ShowTip('<b>Resource Error:</b>1054 <br />
<b>OS:</b> Windows Xp <br />
<b> Ram:</b> 1024MB <br />
<b> CPU:</b> Corei7-5130 <br />')">Error 1054</span>
```

Comment: Can you show the complete rendered HTML for the `<span>` element?

Comment: [The Great Escapism (Or: What You Need To Know To Work With Text Within Text)](http://kunststube.net/escapism/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A. You should replace `printf` because the arguments are not complete you have `4` `%s` in `$lang['tip1054']`

```
printf ($lang['tip1054'],$os,$ram,$cpu);
```

With

```
printf ($lang['tip1054'],"Fist Message", $os,$ram,$cpu);
```

B. You should remove all white spaces and line breaks

```
$lang['tip1054'] = trim($lang['tip1054']);
$lang['tip1054'] = str_replace(array("\r","\n"), "", $lang['tip1054']);
```

[See Demo](http://codepad.viper-7.com/nj0b3m)

Answer (score 0):

You can't have line breaks in a string in JavaScript.  Strip them out with PHP using `str_replace("\n", '', $lang...)` or something.

Comment: and what's your idea how to use line breaks?

Comment: If you want to use line breaks in JavaScript you have to use the `"\n"` literal.  It's generally not a good idea to mix JS with PHP for a variety of reasons, this being one.